# Wait until AdMob Ads are loaded - sometimes ads not showing

Tags: android, show, admob

Hey guys,
I searched the last 4 hours to solve this issue, I wasn't able to do so, so I finally decided to post the question here.

2 Problems,
first:
Everything added, implemented like described in the manual, testAds work fine (a month ago, also real ads did fine - without a change -at least one, i realized) BUT no real ads are showing, -maybe? while connected on usb - that time it always sends the "use code xxxxx to show test ads" but sometimes it also shows some ads... and i really want to **understand** why and when ads are showing.
my testdevice is a htc hero, connected via USB, but with wifi enabled, and internet, so there shouldn't be a problem.
month a ago, ads were showing without problems at all. (all the time)

second:
sometimes no ads are showing at all, usb disconnected, internet on, nothings happens, i can wait for minutes without an single ad showing.
could it be because its the debug version running on my phone? havent found a solution, so i hoped maybe brain-storming :=) could solve this one!

Is there maybe a way to force-load an ad .. and check if its displayed correctly? Sometimes after 30 seconds.. an ad appears. sometimes... rare .. sometimes... :=//

thanks a lot for any feedback,
cV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the reporting on AdMob?  It may be that you made a request, but they didn't have an ad to fill your request.

We found this was a regular occurrence and so we use multiple ad sources.

Comment: f*** ... sry, pressed enter and the commend was posted... was really angry yesterday.. but decided to test adwhirl and multiple networks .. and taataaa today everythings works fine again.. even admob ads are showing again using the adwhirl api!

Comment: one more problems seems to appear: in log it says something like: Dart is... <number ... of number> Showing ad... *giving the information* Valid Adapter, calling handler ---- everything seems fine, but no ad is showing in the app.. i ain't got no idea, whats the problem. maybe someone does?

Comment: hmmm... can you provide the full dump?